# Twitter Api: Why do I get errors, although the rate limit results look good?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter

I'm using the Twitter API to check how many of the 180 possible Twitter lookups per 15 minutes are still left.

```
T.get('application/rate_limit_status', { resources: 'search' }, searchLimit);

function searchLimit(err, data, response) {
    if(err) {
        console.log('2. SearchLimit Error: ' + err);
        console.log('2. Start next search in 20 Minutes');
        setTimeout(rtBot, 1000 * 60 * 20);      
    }
    else {
        var tweetSearch = data.resources.search['/search/tweets'].remaining;

        if(tweetSearch > 0) {
          console.log('2. Remaining tweet searchs: ' + tweetSearch);
          startSearch();
        }
        else {
            console.log('2. Possible tweet searchs exceeded: ' + tweetSearch);
            console.log('2. Start next search in 20 Minutes');
            setTimeout(rtBot, 1000 * 60 * 20);
        }
    }
}
```

This function shall be controlled:

```
T.get('search/tweets', {
    q: 'cookies',
    lang: 'en',
    count: 500,
    result_type: 'recent'
}, gotData);
```

Although my variable `tweetSearch` is not zero, it happens that twitter stops my search and returns the error code `rate limit exceeded`. Why?

How much searchs still remain is different. One Time it broke off at 40, another time at 14. Why?

Therefore: "Lastly, there may be times in which the rate limit values that we return are inconsistent, or cases where no headers are returned at all. Perhaps memcache has been reset, or one memcache was busy so the system spoke to a different instance: the values may be inconsistent now and again. The system makes a best effort to maintain consistency, but errs towards giving an application extra calls if there is an inconsistency."

Comment: maybe twitter has limit for api calls per minute

Comment: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limiting